# Creating first add-on to Open Source project with Bitbucket

Tags: project-management, version-control-systems

I wish to install my first add-on to my newly acquired Bitbucket open source project.

Should it be setup and developed on its on branch and then imported in when approved and working
OR
Edit the files locally and then add a 1.1 tag?

In the past before using git I have used

Version 1.1 (My first add-on)
Version 1.2 (Small changes to files, change to UK language)
Version 1.3 (My second add-on)

Is this where GitFlow comes in?

Comment: This is more a question on how to organize your workflow and structure your source code. You should perhaps rummage in [git's documentation](http://git-scm.com/doc) (particularly the book and workflow discussions), and ask around at [SO](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about organizing source code and git usage, more relevant on StackOverflow

Comment: @vonbrand Incorrect. This would be off-topic on SO.

Comment: The appropriate site is probably [programmers.se].

Comment: @curiousdannii what's wrong with having this on the site?

Comment: @Zizouz212 The details of branch management are completely tangential to open source, and the way this is phrased is completely opinion based. If it was migrated to Programmers then it could be seen as a best-practices question.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'd really appreciate having a discussion on meta about this. Can you start one?